# Abel's Theorem of 2nd Order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem Statement:

Verify that the given functions $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ satisfy the corresponding homogeneous equation; and then... (the rest doesn't matter for my question)

$$ ty'' - (1+t)y' + y = t^2e^{2t} \quad t>0, \quad y_{1}(t)=1+t, \quad y_{2}(t) = e^{t} $$

Question:

So the straightforward way to do this is to just plug the equations and respective derivatives into the ODE like the problem wants. But another answer to this problem could be to compute the Wronskian and analyzing the result appropriately or potentially evaluating the Wronskian by Abel's Theorem:

$$W(1+t,e^{t})(t) = c\thinspace exp[-\int{\frac{-(1+t)}{t} \, dt} = c\,t\,e^{t} $$

So the issue in using Abels Theorem is that you have to determine if the constant c is 0 or not, but it's not clear to me how you would go about finding out what the value of the constant $c$ is. One could compare what you get with Abel's Theorem to the computation that you get from the Wronskian calculation, but then it seems to me that Abel's Theorem is just kind of redundant if one needs to compute the full Wronskian anyways to find c.

So suppose I were to answer this problem using Abel's Theorem instead of what the question asks, how can I assert that $c \ne 0$ , and consequentially that $y_{1}(t)$ and $y_{2}(t)$ are indeed solutions to the corresponding homogeneous equation of the ODE given above?

edit: Because of the condition that $t>0$, then I don't think that the constant c would matter in this case since for any $t$ the Wronskian would be non-zero. I'm not sure if this thought process is accurate though.